# Spring Boot tries to run an embedded Tomcat when deployed as traditional war

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to build Spring Boot application with a application context hierarchy and deploy it in a traditional way to a standalone Tomcat.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797602/spring-boot-application-with-context-hierarchy-tries-to-start-an-embedded-tomcat) but it remains unresolved and I cannot make a comment there because of lack of reputation.

Surprisingly to me, **changing the application context structure to flat fixes the issue**, but that is not an option for me.

I am using `Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE` and `Apache Tomcat/9.0.16`.

**Repository**: https://github.com/artszko/spring-war-contexts

Here is my `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application
                   .parent(ParentConfig.class)
                   .child(ChildConfig.class);
  }

  //But this works
  /*@Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application
                   .sources(ParentConfig.class, ChildConfig.class);
  }*/

}
```

And the stacktrace I am receiving:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:389)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:413)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4980)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:413)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4980)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-war-contexts</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@Configuration` in your `ParentConfig` and `ChildConfig`?

Comment: Yes, it gives the following stacktrace then:
`Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
...`
Most probably because neither context has auto configuration enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be that you have packaged all tomcat libraries inside your war. Just look inside it and determine if that's true. If so, mark your tomcat dependency provided, so it won't get into final war.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is marked as provided already. I have added pom to the description.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like, its trying to find the embedded tomcat classes and throwing the error as you are deploying for external tomcat.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
```

Please make the change in pom to provide the spring-boot-starter-web dependency at runtime, Which will pick it up from the external tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```